# Yii2 : Search in Gridview using Pjax POST but Pagination

Tags: php, gridview, pagination, yii2, pjax

I use Pjax library for Yii2 to refresh data without reloading page.

```
<?php \yii\widgets\Pjax::begin(['id' => 'some-id-you-like',
    'timeout' => false,
    'enablePushState' => false,
    'clientOptions' => ['method' => 'POST']]);

echo GridView::widget([
    ....
]); 

\yii\widgets\Pjax::end(); ?>
```

Everything is ok. But i want to make pagination works with GET request (I want to see `?page=` in url ).

Any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set 'enablePushState' => true or remove it (default value true).

Comment: It works! Tnx. Я потратил кучу времени, а тут всего лишь слов надо сменить. Вы меня выручили!!!

Comment: when i change to POST, the pagination doesn't work. and the filter posts to web's main page. any idea why?

Comment: after type `POST`, i had to add this for filters to work. but pagination doesn't work. `'url' => Url::to(['/test/default/dashboard'])`